# calculating a count (number of distinct key's in an object) in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular code, see below.

What I'd like to achieve is - for each user - find out the "count" for each activity type.

**What I'd like to achieve is:


John Thompson = 2 Deal

Bill Gates    = 3 Deal

Billy Wellington = 2 Deal, 1 Meeting**

The activity id's are the same in the activities object, and the $scope.activities.

Bit stuck here, any idea on how to either a) Write a function to get the COUNT or b) Do something clever in the HTML element with a ng-repeat and group or something.

```
$scope.competitionDetails = {
        end_date: "2014-03-01",
        users: [{
            id: 2,
            name: "John Thompson",
            activities: [{ //This is all their activities
                id: 6431,
                time: (57).minutes().ago(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }]
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "Bill Gates",
            activities: [{ //This is all their activities
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }]
        }, {
            id: 1,
            name: "Billy Wellington",
            activities: [{ //This is all their activities
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6432,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 100
            }]
        }]
    };

    $scope.activities = [{
        id: 6431,
        name: "Deal",
        points: 20
    }, {
        id: 6432,
        name: "Meeting",
        points: 100
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4757/

Just using some regular js, with a tiny bit of angular:

```
// create a lookup    
var lookup = {};
angular.forEach($scope.activities, function(activity){
    lookup[activity.id] = activity;
});

// calculate the results
angular.forEach($scope.competitionDetails.users, function(user){
    user.results = {};
    angular.forEach(user.activities, function(activity){
        var name = lookup[activity.id].name;
        if(!user.results[name]){
            user.results[name] = 1;
        }else{                
            user.results[name] += 1;            
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: Damn that's perfect. Thanks @Matt Way!

Comment: If I wanted to only pull the results for one user, could I just create a function that passes in the userId and doesnt do a loop, but a look up or? How would you best approach that?

Comment: Yeah, just break apart my answer into a function that you could plug a single user into, and run it whenever you need a result.